# some notational doubt on probability distribution on metric space.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

$P: \mathcal{M}_{f i n}(X) \rightarrow \mathcal{M}_{f i n}(X)$ be a Markov operator, $\mathcal{M}_{f i n}(X)$ be the space of all be the set of all Borel finite
measures on $X$. $\{X_n\}_{n\ge 0}$ be a homogeneous Markov chain on $X$, such that $PL(X_n)=L(X_{n+1})$, where $L(X_n)$ denotes the distribution of $X_n$.

1. Could anyone tell me what does the last sentence means mathematically? does it mean if that if $L(X_n)$ is given by some probability measure say $\mu_n$ then $P\mu_n=\mu_{n+1}$?
2. Could anyone explain to me the action of $P$ in a bit detail?
3. Why $P\mu_n=\mu_{n+1}$? $\mu_n, \mu_{n+1}\in \mathcal M_1(X)$. $X$ is a polish space.
4. On page 3, what is the assumption $H$ means geometrically or analytically in simple words, means what is the picture behind the assumption? Thanks!

based on page $1,2,3$ of

<sup>1</sup>Rafał Kapica, Maciej Ślȩczka: *Law of large numbers for random iteration*; [DOI:10.1080/10236198.2017.1332054](https://doi.org/10.1080/10236198.2017.1332054)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1). Yes. Yes.

2). I'm not sure what you're asking. Maybe this will help. Given the Markov chain $(X_n)_n$ (with initial distribution $\mu_0$ for $X_0$), we can ask what the distribution of $X_1$ is. If $\overline{P}$ is the transition matrix for the Markov chain, i.e. $\mathbb P(X_1=x | X_0 = y) = \mu_0(y)\overline{P}_{xy}$, then the distribution of $X_1$ is given by $\mu_1(x) = \sum_y \mu_0(y)\overline{P}_{xy}$, so the map $P$ is given explicitly as $P(\mu)(x) = \sum_y \mu(y)\overline{P}_{xy}$. The point is that, if we are given the distribution of $X_n$, i.e. the probability distribution of being at certain states of the Markov chain at time $n$, then $P$ finds the probability distribution of being at certain states of the Markov chain at time $n+1$.

3). I have no idea what you're trying to ask here, but hopefully my answer to (2) helps.

4). $\mu_*$ is the stationary distribution of the Markov chain; you should think of it as the "perfectly mixed" distribution (though that is sometimes misleading). For example, if the Markov chain is a random walk on a finite, regular graph, then $\mu_*$ is the uniform distribution. What assumption $H$ is saying is that you have rapid convergence to the stationary distribution: if you know you start off at a given state $x$, then after $n$ iterations, you are very close to being equally likely to be anywhere. The exact form of having a continuous function $\gamma(x)$ is more for technical reasons (see point (ii) of remark 1 for a nice corollary of that technical part of assumption H), but the main part is that $q^n$, rapid convergence.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer, just before accepting it, let me ask regarding the assumption $H$ again, why do we need the existence of that $\gamma(x)$? what role that $\gamma(x)$ is playing?

Comment: Also, you explained something with transition matrix, but this is a Markov chain with uncountable state-space, so does your explanation works for the Markov operator $P$? Do you mean: the role of transition matrix in finite state-space Markov chain is kind of same as Markov operator $P$   in uncountable state-space Markov chain?

Comment: @miosaki for your first comment, have you read the proof of anything? like I said, assumption H implies point (ii) of remark 1, and it's used later in the proof. you should read to find out. for your second comment, I don't see why countable vs uncountable would make a difference for my explanation

Comment: Thank you so much, I just understand your point, now another question if you have time please answer me whenever you feel convenient: the paper says about law of large numbers, now from my elementary knowledge of probability theory and measure theory, I know that there are two forms of law of large number: weak law and strong law.  Both assume that the random variables are IID i.e independent, identically distributed, now could you tell me whether the random variables they are considering are IID or not?

Comment: They say $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n,\dots$ forms a homogeneous Markov chain, does it mean that  $X_i$ are IID for all $i$? If may I ask, they establish a strong law of large number for the chain, right?

Comment: Sorry, they are proving law of large number for $\psi(X_1),\dots, \psi(X_n),\dots$ for some $\psi$ continuous. So,  $\psi(X_1),\dots, \psi(X_n),\dots$  are IID?

Comment: The strong law of large numbers concerns almost sure convergence, whereas the weak law of large numbers concerns convergence in probability. This paper is thus talking about a weak law of large numbers. I have seen the weak and strong laws of large numbers formulated for sequences of random variables that are just independent, not necessarily i.i.d.. There are also weak/strong laws of large numbers for time homogeneous Markov chains. The $X_i$'s (and therefore the $\psi(X_i)$'s) are most certainly not independent; let the $X_i$'s be the position of a simple random walk on $\mathbb{Z}$ after

Comment: $i$ steps, for example. I am confused, though, why you are trying to put a label on their theorem. They state their theorem very precisely, so just read what it says rather than trying to fit it into some box.